# Implicit conversion of Scala Map

Tags: java, json, scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am building a custom json parser using an implicits design pattern in scala > this is more an exercise to master the implicits system  ( i understand there are libraries that do Json parsing)

I can get my json parser to serialize everything up to maps, but the compiler for whatever reason does not seem able to find my implicit JsonMap -> basically I want to parse a string containing key value pairs, put it into a scala Map and then pass that into my custom JsonMap class. This approach works for regular arrays, but not Maps.

The error returned is `No implicits found for parameter converter JsonValue[Map[String, Json]]`

My implicit converter is supposed to be the MapJsonValue of the JsonValue class -> the apply method of the Json object takes the implicit converter. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
package Json

sealed trait Json

object Json {
  case class JsonString( value: String) extends Json {
    override def toString: String = value
  }
  case class JsonNumber(value: Double) extends Json{
    override def toString: String = value.toString
  }
  case class JsonBoolean(value: Boolean) extends Json{
    override def toString: String = value.toString
  }
  case class JsonNull(value: Null) extends Json{
    override def toString: String = value
  }
  case class JsonList(items: Json*) extends Json

  case class JsonMap(items: Map[String,Json]) extends Json

  object JsonMap{
    def fromString(x: String): Json = {
      var map = x.stripPrefix("{").stripSuffix("}").  split(",").map(_.split(":")).map { case Array(k, v) => (k, Json.fromString(v) ) }.toMap
      map = Json(map)  Error: No implicits found for parameter converter JsonValue[Map[String, Json]]
    }


  }

  object JsonList {
    def fromString(x: String): Json = Json(x.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]") .split(",").toSeq)


  }

  def apply[T](x:T)(implicit converter: JsonValue[T]): Json = converter.serialize(x)

  def fromString(x: String): Json = x match {
    case x if x.startsWith("[") => JsonList.fromString(x)
    case x if x.startsWith("{") => JsonMap.fromString(x)
    case "null" => new JsonNull(value = null)
    case "True" => new JsonBoolean(true)
    case "False"=> new JsonBoolean(false)
    case _ => new JsonString(x)
  }



 }

trait JsonValue[T] {

  def serialize(t: T): Json

}

object JsonValue{
  implicit object StringJsonValue extends JsonValue[String]{
    def serialize(t: String): Json.JsonString = Json.JsonString(t)
  }
  implicit object NumJsonValue extends JsonValue[Double]{
    def serialize(t: Double): Json.JsonNumber = Json.JsonNumber(t)
  }
  implicit object BooleanJsonValue extends JsonValue[Boolean]{
    def serialize(t: Boolean): Json.JsonBoolean = Json.JsonBoolean(t)
  }

  implicit object NullJsonValue extends JsonValue[Null]{
    def serialize(t: Null): Json.JsonNull = Json.JsonNull(t)
  }



  implicit def MapJsonValue[T: JsonValue]: JsonValue[Map[String, T]] = new JsonValue[Map[String, T]]{
    def serialize(t:  Map[String, T]):Json.JsonMap = {
      Json.JsonMap(t.map(t => t._1 -> implicitly[JsonValue[T]].serialize(t._2) )    )
    }
  }

  implicit def SeqJsonValue[T: JsonValue]: JsonValue[Seq[T]] = new JsonValue[Seq[T]]{
    def serialize(t: Seq[T]):Json.JsonList = {
      Json.JsonList(t.map(implicitly[JsonValue[T]].serialize):_*)
    }
  }




}
```

Comment: You don't have a `JsonValue[Json]` that si why the `Map` fails - Even more, you don't need all that, you can just create a `JsonMap` directly in that case.